# Generate JSON Schema from JSON Data Programmatically

Tags: c#, json, schema

I want generate json schema from json  datafile, like below.(this is generated with online tool, http://jsonschema.net/)
is it possible with JSON.NET or any other?

Json DataFile :

```
{
  "graph": [
    {
      "id": 453,
      "cid": 143,
      "title": "graph1",
      "description": "",
      "thumbnailPath": "art.jpg",
      "detailPath": "art.jpg",
      "link": "www.test.html",
      "author": "graph Team"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "cid": 121,
      "title": "graph2",
      "description": "",
      "thumbnailPath": "art2.jpg",
      "detailPath": "art2.jpg",
      "link": "www.test2.html",
      "author": "graph Team"
    }
  ]
}
```

OutPut:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "/",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "graph": {
      "id": "graph",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "id": "id",
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "cid": {
            "id": "cid",
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "title": {
            "id": "title",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "description": {
            "id": "description",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "thumbnailPath": {
            "id": "thumbnailPath",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "detailPath": {
            "id": "detailPath",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "link": {
            "id": "link",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "author": {
            "id": "author",
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my goal is not using a tool because i want generate it on runtime in program.

Comment: Try this tool. It generate a json based on query pattern.
https://github.com/rollrodrig/customjsonbuilder

Answer (score 1):

Ok I did this:

1. download the visual studio extension https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b4515ef8-a518-41ca-b48c-bb1fd4e6faf7
2. rename the .vsix file to .zip
3. extract the zip file to arbitrary folder
4. reference the Microsoft.Json.SchemaExtension.dll and Microsoft.Json.SchemaProducer.dll
5. make sure your project is beeing a .net framework 4.5 project (as these 2 assemblies are build with .net 4.5, I didnt find those assemblies elsewhere on the net)
6. use this code to get the JSON schema from your JSON
7. though I can not guarantee to you that this approach is legal

-

```
string json = @"{
  ""graph"": [
    {
      ""id"": 453,
      ""cid"": 143,
      ""title"": ""graph1"",
      ""description"": """",
      ""thumbnailPath"": ""art.jpg"",
      ""detailPath"": ""art.jpg"",
      ""link"": ""www.test.html"",
      ""author"": ""graph Team""
    },
    {
      ""id"": 12,
      ""cid"": 121,
      ""title"": ""graph2"",
      ""description"": """",
      ""thumbnailPath"": ""art2.jpg"",
      ""detailPath"": ""art2.jpg"",
      ""link"": ""www.test2.html"",
      ""author"": ""graph Team""
    }
  ]
}";
string jsonSchema = Microsoft.Json.SchemaProducer.SchemaBuilder.CreateSchema(json);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but in your part I of your solution ther is a code that we haven't it. (before string schemaJson=...) , in theory we only have a well known json file and we want get it Json Schema.

Comment: Thanks @Michal Hainc, i think your methood is a soloution, but unfortunately i work on Xamarin and my project use .NET 2.